# Netflix preview video production

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, preview, thumbnails

Netflix auto-plays a 20s, 30s video preview in the background if a video is selected or we hover the mouse pointer on them. I was trying to play with them, but couldn't understand how this preview "video production" is done.

Is there any information or insights how these previews are generated? Are they a random portion of the video, or what?

Alternatively, if you have a good suggestion of how to select a portion of video, please share.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but most likely it is the trailer or a specificaly for Netflix edited Teaser

Comment: I noticed sometimes they play the trailer, but sometimes just a portion of the movie.